# Can't print map per address

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Following Google Map Api 3 example.

At the bottom of the body, it also includes jquery file and this below

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<div id="map_canvas" class="address" style=" width: 100%; height: 200px;">San Francisco</div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<div id="map_canvas" class="address" style=" width: 100%; height: 200px;">San Diego</div>
</td></tr><tr><td>
<div id="map_canvas" class="address" style=" width: 100%; height: 200px;">San Jose</div>
</td></tr></table>
```

JQuery

```
var map;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}

var address = $(".address");
var el;
address.each(function(){
   el = $(this).text();
   codeAddress(el);
});


function codeAddress(address) {
    alert(address);
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My first attempt working with googleMap Api 3 - I looked around for answer.

There will be dynamic multiple addresses printing out in each table row. So grab each address from div.address and each address is converted into lat and longitude and then display map.

But right now it is not checking each or looping all address to be converted into lat and longitude before map is displayed with positioned marker.

Why isn't it looping each address? Is there any way to grab and loop through addresses from div.address as text and convert it to display map?

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tu2zjvb9/1/)

As you can see, there is 1 incorrect map appearing on jsfiddle :(

**Updated #1**

Managed to get one map appear with all markers, but still couldn't get 3 **separate maps** with each marker  per address. Couldn't figure why it only printed one map with markers in first row.

Appreciate help and insight if any

Help Please

Comment: IDs are unique. You can't have 3 map containers with the same ID and create only 1 map instance.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - ah there will be thousands of addresses, so I have to add for example map_canvas1, map_canvas2..etc? but the problem is how to loop to add number into map_canvas inside initialize()? hmm

Comment: Thousands of addresses = thousands of maps?

Comment: @MrUpsidown - yes it is literal but more than 20 addresses - means more than 20 maps. I could add div class="map_canvas#" manually but with map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas') how to tell it to find map_canvas#? # is the number

Comment: @MrUpsidown - is there any way to do that?

Comment: I find it a bit weird to create 20 maps if you have 20 addresses to show. What's the point? Further to that, there are limitations with the geocoder (you can't geocode 20 addresses in a loop like that). I think you should review your project before start.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - yeah agreed. maybe try Static Image Google Map it would be better.