# Go next to append map image in each container issue

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<div class="postcode map-wt"> 980005</div>
<div class="postcode map-wt"> 97005</div>       
<div class="postcode map-wt"> 30005</div>
```

JQuery

```
var postcode = $(".postcode");
    var el = postcode;
    postcode.each(function(){
       el = $(this).text();
       postMap(el);
    });


    function postMap(postcode){
      container = $('.map-wt')
      container.append('<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + postcode + '"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + postcode +'&markers=' + postcode + '&zoom=12&scale=false&size=250x275&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&sensor=false"' + "/></a>");
    }
```

The problem is that it prints all images in same container in first row. Have been trying to find different ways around but seem that each(function) does not go through each postcode and append map.

How to make it append each image in each div?

Help please and appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the target element as an argument, along with the post code to `postMap()`.

```js
var postcode = $(".postcode");
postcode.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      postcode = $this.text();
  postMap($this, postcode);
});


function postMap($el, postcode) {
  $el.append('<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + postcode + '"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + postcode + '&markers=' + postcode + '&zoom=12&scale=false&size=250x275&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&sensor=false"' + "/></a>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postcode map-wt">98005</div>
<div class="postcode map-wt">97005</div>
<div class="postcode map-wt">30005</div>
```

In this case since `postcode` and `map-wt` are the same, you can pass `this` reference to `postMap`

Comment: I knew something wrong with codes. Thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using `.append( callback )` as follows:

```
$('.postcode').append(function() {
    var postcode = $(this).text();
    return '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + postcode + '"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + postcode +'&markers=' + postcode + '&zoom=12&scale=false&size=250x275&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&sensor=false"' + "/></a>";
});
```

```js
$('.postcode').append(function() {
    var postcode = $(this).text();
    return '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + postcode + '"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + postcode +'&markers=' + postcode + '&zoom=12&scale=false&size=250x275&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&sensor=false"' + "/></a>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postcode map-wt">98005</div>
<div class="postcode map-wt">97005</div>
<div class="postcode map-wt">30005</div>
```

Or if you have to use a function you can pass `this` to the function as follows:

```
$('.postcode').append(function() {
    return postMap.apply(this);
});

function postMap() {
    var postcode = $(this).text();
    return '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + postcode + '"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + postcode +'&markers=' + postcode + '&zoom=12&scale=false&size=250x275&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&sensor=false"' + "/></a>";
}
```

```js
    $('.postcode').append(function() {
        return postMap.apply(this);
    });
    
    function postMap() {
        var postcode = $(this).text();
        return '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + postcode + '"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + postcode +'&markers=' + postcode + '&zoom=12&scale=false&size=250x275&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&sensor=false"' + "/></a>";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="postcode map-wt">98005</div>
    <div class="postcode map-wt">97005</div>
    <div class="postcode map-wt">30005</div>
```

Comment: would it be same for interactive map which get element id? or it is not possible?

Comment: Could you provide more information on what kind of interactive map you have in mind?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843584/cant-print-map-per-address?noredirect=1#comment42257025_26843584 -> i tried but it prints all markers in one map and I am not sure how to separate maps per postcode. Any suggestion appreciated.